# I get error message "MEMORY SIZE REDUCED" occasionally at boot time - NOT every time. What to do?

Tags: boot, ram

So far, simply restarting gets rid of this.

Ubuntu 18.04, Gnome Metacity,
Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
7.7 GiB in "About This Computer"  I think it's got 8 Gig installed.

Comment: If I saw that message; I'd be checking/validating the health of the hardware more than the OS.  If I felt it was the OS, I'd be booting another OS (*live* if only a single OS is installed; using media OR *live* media existing on the internal drive via `grub` change) to see if it occurs there too - ie. hardware issues confirmation.

Comment: If you are using a Dell system, that message means that one of your RAM DIMMs is bad. The system will section off part of the RAM that is failing the checksums, but it's on you to do something about it.

Comment: It's a custom built system, Intel board.

Would Ubuntu react the same way as in the Dell, if it's a memory problem?

I'll try reseating the ram.

Any other ideas would be welcome !